Should component store updaters always return a completely fresh state object
I can't wrap my head around the concept of reducers/updaters always returning a fresh state object with a certain piece of it updated with the new value. However, should the copy always be deep or is a shallow one sufficient?
I mean in the examples this is mostly done with the spread (...) operator. However, it clones only first level primitives and for example an array is not decoupled but rather present in the new object as a shared reference. Is it ok to do it this way?
Take a look at an official example that confused me: https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/read#debounce-selectors. A state in the form:
{movies: [], moviesPerPage: 10, currentPageIndex: 0}

is updated this way:
  // Updates how many movies per page should be displayed
  readonly updateMoviesPerPage = this.updater((state, moviesPerPage: number) => ({
    ...state,
    moviesPerPage, // updates with new value
  }));

which means movies are shallowly copied. Is it all right?

Yes, that's totally fine (typically). If all members are immutable (here by definition, not technically enforced) then you can always "just copy" them. No need to deep clone.

Yeah, top-level properties (movies, moviesPerPage, currentPageIndex) are copied to a new object.
The movies array is not deeply copied; instead, the reference to the original movies array is copied.
Hence you need to handle it carefully. In addition to the updater, it required some time deep copy.

Yes, so I'm aware how this way of copying works, I also know that the updated object does not === the object it was created from, which may be needed to trigger change detection. However what do you mean by saying I should handle the array copied this way carefully? What kind of problems can I run into?

So in, when you are updating movies, or any Array use spread operator. eg.
setMoives([...moives, newMoives])
